# Test of significance for a nonlinear trend in time series analyses, ARIMA

Tags: time-series, arima

I have water temperature data consisting of monthly means for 20 years. As one would expect there is a definite seasonal/cyclical pattern. I wish to model the time series data by fitting an ARIMA model.

Two questions:

1. Would this be an appropriate analysis for temperature data?
2. How do I test if there is a significant trend (a p-value would be nice!) of increasing water temperature in this data which is clearly nonlinear?

   ```
     Year  Month   Temperature
     1953  March   21.88302419
     1953  April   21.22354167
     1953  May 19.98760753
     1953  June    18.39943056
     1953  July    16.94803763
     1953  August  16.71372312
     1953  September   17.46852778
     1953  October 18.12665323
     1953  November    19.29626389
     1953  December    19.9861828
     1954  January 20.86797043
     1954  February    21.91311012
     1954  March   22.3521371
     1954  April   20.94972222
     1954  May 20.34298387
     1954  June    18.39666667
     1954  July    17.18486559
     1954  August  17.13916667
     1954  September   17.35176389
     1954  October 18.30989247
     1954  November    19.14590278
     1954  December    20.25358871
     1955  January 21.8128629
     1955  February    22.73234195
     1955  March   21.60393817
     1955  April   20.92319444
     1955  May 20.09857527
     1955  June    18.16069444
     1955  July    17.24068641
     1955  August  17.14547043
     1955  September   16.676875
     1955  October 17.31141129
     1955  November    19.70297222
     1955  December    20.0072043
     1956  January 21.77598118
     1956  February    21.62849702
     1956  March   21.94706989
     1956  April   20.6965
     1956  May 19.05202957
     1956  June    17.81277778
     1956  July    17.3078629
     1956  August  17.35629032
     1956  September   17.84531944
     1956  October 18.0919086
     1956  November    19.68886111
     1956  December    20.42611559
     1957  January 21.82801075
     1957  February    22.76324405
     1957  March   22.8733109
     1957  April   21.89454167
     1957  May 20.41923387
     1957  June    18.85397222
     1957  July    18.36353495
     1957  August  17.7866218
     1957  September   18.141875
     1957  October 18.99646505
     1957  November    19.38388889
     1957  December    20.64235215
     1958  January 21.35995968
     1958  February    21.56925595
     1958  March   23.04430108
     1958  April   21.3755
     1958  May 20.06209677
     1958  June    18.8416968
     1958  July    17.77298387
     1958  August  17.71418011
     1958  September   17.39784722
     1958  October 17.88056452
     1958  November    19.88647222
     1958  December    21.30474462
     1959  January 22.51991925
     1959  February    23.35799107
     1959  March   22.5344086
     1959  April   22.08238889
     1959  May 20.04969086
     1959  June    19.00790278
     1959  July    18.27353495
     1959  August  17.55283984
     1959  September   17.22833333
     1959  October 18.01680108
     1959  November    18.6775
     1959  December    19.8469086
     1960  January 20.68198925
     1960  February    21.83154762
     1960  March   21.50378073
     1960  April   20.34733796
     1960  May 19.58559588
     1960  June    18.45406456
     1960  July    17.53125
     1960  August  16.96117944
     1960  September   16.98905903
     1960  October 17.73582997
     1960  November    18.65800694
     1960  December    19.32586694
     1961  January 19.71767473
     1961  February    21.04120651
     1961  March   21.35288306
     1961  April   20.30002431
     1961  May 18.6331754
     1961  June    18.62307639
     1961  July    18.2453629
     1961  August  16.99882056
     1961  September   17.33630194
     1961  October 16.92414798
     1961  November    18.00218056
     1961  December    18.73533154
     1962  January 19.35255376
     1962  February    20.21777565
     1962  March   21.21165323
     1962  April   20.21122222
     1962  May 19.51232527
     1962  June    18.25903472
     1962  July    17.53709677
     1962  August  16.88536713
     1962  September   16.02052778
     1962  October 17.28112903
     1962  November    18.13883333
     1962  December    19.95607527
     1963  January 21.23651882
     1963  February    19.9141523
     1963  March   21.89069892
     1963  April   21.20695833
     1963  May 19.74677419
     1963  June    18.01259722
     1963  July    17.27166667
     1963  August  16.63431452
     1963  September   16.78509722
     1963  October 18.14424731
     1963  November    19.29784722
     1963  December    18.66950269
     1964  January 22.3822043
     1964  February    21.98738095
     1964  March   22.06516129
     1964  April   20.77536364
     1964  May 19.60976277
     1964  June    17.69825347
     1964  July    17.47606586
     1964  August  16.81932997
     1964  September   17.18971597
     1964  October 17.78017742
     1964  November    19.022725
     1964  December    19.98706116
     1965  January 20.62890995
     1965  February    21.86117039
     1965  March   21.76144624
     1965  April   21.41317694
     1965  May 19.89478226
     1965  June    18.14042639
     1965  July    16.53863575
     1965  August  17.4485
     1965  September   17.38953973
     1965  October 17.79755645
     1965  November    19.54316042
     1965  December    20.5874375
     1966  January 21.33427016
     1966  February    22.30857515
     1966  March   21.52931855
     1966  April   21.37102778
     1966  May 20.02285954
     1966  June    18.68837361
     1966  July    18.03406653
     1966  August  17.54710551
     1966  September   18.25538665
     1966  October 18.1833172
     1966  November    19.20074583
     1966  December    20.33642742
     1967  January 21.07148185
     1967  February    22.28252799
     1967  March   21.35484005
     1967  April   20.18232083
     1967  May 18.87129435
     1967  June    18.12438472
     1967  July    17.34492215
     1967  August  17.27377688
     1967  September   16.92026389
     1967  October 17.54733871
     1967  November    18.37069444
     1967  December    19.83104839
     1968  January 21.33081989
     1968  February    21.68643155
     1968  March   21.64960081
     1968  April   20.69278889
     1968  May 18.98352957
     1968  June    18.3307
     1968  July    17.23593011
     1968  August  16.94599866
     1968  September   16.48676389
     1968  October 16.9316371
     1968  November    17.66956806
     1968  December    19.41569489
     1969  January 21.37015591
     1969  February    20.70526488
     1969  March   21.64435081
     1969  April   20.97368472
     1969  May 20.4197836
     1969  June    18.31870833
     1969  July    17.4229328
     1969  August  17.10003226
     1969  September   17.36448056
     1969  October 18.07489785
     1969  November    18.97591528
     1969  December    20.51862231
     1970  January 22.03919489
     1970  February    21.64364487
     1970  March   21.24479032
     1970  April   20.28298611
     1970  May 19.29274059
     1970  June    17.73382639
     1970  July    16.55055511
     1970  August  16.43872446
     1970  September   17.48788472
     1970  October 17.9552638
     1970  November    19.17982222
     1970  December    19.68649597
     1971  January 21.57199866
     1971  February    21.76181178
     1971  March   21.11755511
     1971  April   20.01336667
     1971  May 19.05388978
     1971  June    18.52273333
     1971  July    17.39878226
     1971  August  16.3497836
     1971  September   17.0700125
     1971  October 18.32019758
     1971  November    18.96098333
     1971  December    19.1836586
   ```

Comment: Are you willing to assume a parametric form of the trend (e.g. linear, quadratic etc. with unknown coefficients) or would you rather allow the trend to take whatever weird shape? The former case is simpler: you would include relevant variables in the model (e.g. a linearly or quadratically increasing deterministic series; this would turn the model from ARIMA to ARIMAX), and get the estimates of their coefficients (and p-values, too).

Comment: Dear Richard, thank you, as the temperature data are of seawater in a natural setting, I think I would be okay assuming they follow some sort of parametric trend. How would I go about determining/including relevant variables in the model as you allude to? Is there perhaps an example on the web that spells out how to do this?

Comment: See e.g. Rob J Hyndman's [blog post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). He also discusses R functions for this. Look at the documentation for these functions to see exactly how they work. The relevant trend variables could be $x_1=\{1,2,...,t\}$, $x_1=\{1^2,2^2,...,t^2\}$ for a linear and a quadratic term.

Comment: Proper transformations of the data including Generalized Least Squares (weighted regression) or properly segmenting the data due to parameter transiency while incorporating deterministic structure can be much more efficient. Post your data and we can have a comparative analysis highlighting the differences between different methods..

Comment: Thank you Richard and IrishStat! I will post the data immediately in the form of an edit at the end of my original post (due to character limitations of comments), as requested. It would be great to see a comparative analysis, preferably done in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took your 226 values and analyzed them with AUTOBOX. A reasonable ARIMA model [image] was developed BUT a statistically significant change point was detected using the CHOW Test [image] . The most recent 79 values were then examined to identify a suitable model.[image] withe the following Actual/Fit and Forecast graph. [image] . The residuals from this model suggest randomness suggesting a sufficient model. [image] [image] . The forecast plot/table is presented here [image] [image] . Finally the Actual/Cleansed graph showing the two anomalous points is interesting and informative [image] . The statistical summary is here [image] and here [image]  There is no suggestion in the data that would support a "trend" conclusion. Since there is no evidence of a transient error variance or a level shift in the model's errors , any number of simple/uncomplicated approaches should work with data if you ignore the change in parameters over time .

A question to the OP "Are you aware of anything that might have been responsible for the change in parameters ?"

EDIT: TO ANSWER @FORECASTER'S QUESTION REGARDING LIMITS.

I extended the forecast period to 200 periods and reported the multiplier (based upon the psi weights) of the error variance . In short the limits are diverging BUT slowly . Here is the results for the first 24 periods [image] and the periods  97 - 120 [image] and finally the last set (175-200) [image]

Comment: why would the prediction interval in autobox be constant, I would assume that as we go farther out into to the future, the uncertainty increases therefore the prediction interval be more wider? Thank you

Comment: Thank you IrishStat, very impressive, especially to a biologist! To answer your question, I am unaware of anything specific that may have been responsible for the change in parameters..the water temperature is simply at the mercy of the ocean currents in the area and the global atmosphere. When you say that there is no "trend" since there is no transient error variance or level shift in the model's errors which particular summary statistic/statistics are you looking at? And does the significant p-value for Differencing 1Autoregressive-Factor#1 simply mean that the fitted model is accurate?

Comment: @forecaster Confidence limits for a stationary process reach an asymptote.. sometimes quickly (e.g.  white noise) sometimes slowly.

Comment: @Sean The conclusion that there is no identifiable trend comes from the fact that there is no differencing involved in the model. If there was AND if a trend constant was included and significant then there would be a positive conclusion about the existence of trend. Alternatively if AUTOBOX identified the need for a deterministic variable as a result of it's Intervention Detection Procedure ala TSAY 1986 - like  x1={1,2,...,t}, (BUT it didn't) then one could conclude about the need for a  trend

Comment: @forecaster I should have added that this model is non-stationary with psi weights of      1.0
           .5763
           .3321
           .1914
           .1103
           .0636
           .0366
           .0211
           .0122
           .0070
           .0040
           .0023
          1.00
           .5771
           .3326
           .1916
           .1104
           .0636
           .0367
           .0211
           .0122
           .0070
           .0040
           .0023
          etc....

Comment: @forecaster I have added some output to my answer to more fully explain limits

Comment: @IrishStat I think I understand. So even though Differencing with a lag of 1 is significant (according to the summary stats) there is still no trend? So the ARIMA model would be of the form ARIMA(p,0,q) in this case? Hypothetically, what would the Differencing statistics show if there were a trend ?

Comment: correct ... the arima model is (1,0,0)(0,1,0) . The need for a trend would be suggested by the absolute value of (mean/SEM) in the residuals > 2.0 . The statistic in this case is .685943 suggesting non-significance.

Comment: @Sean  correction ! "The conclusion ....in the model " should have been "The conclusion that there is no identifiable trend CAN can come from a stationary model that has no differencing. Your model has differencing.BUT that is not sufficient."

Comment: @IrishStat thank you for your expertise! Earlier you asked if I was aware of anything that may have changed the parameters and I said I was not. Well, I have delved into the metadata and found that a change did occur in how the data were collected. Prior to 1965/4 temperatures were being recorded by TWO loggers side by side, after that time temperatures were recorded by only one logger.

Comment: Amazing that AUTOBOX was able to detect this as a structural break exactly at that time! As a result, I think the most suitable approach therefore is to use data from only one logger through time to avoid a structural break and rerun the analysis..

Comment: I took the most recent 79 values (starting at 1965/4) and found that yet another break point/change point was identified starting at 1968/5. These 42 observations yielded a very simple ARIMA model [(1-B**12)]Y(T) =+     [(1-  .658B** 1)]**-1  [A(T)]

Comment: time ran out on my edit.. here is the complete thought. I took the  recent 79 values (starting at 1965/4) & found that another break point/change point (visually obvious from a plot ) was identified starting at 1968/5.These 42 vlues yielded a very simple but sufficient ARIMA model                                           [(1-B**12)]Y(T) =+     [(1-  .658B** 1)]**-1  [A(T)] which generated essentially non-trending forecasts. The whole idea is to aid the "human eye" in identifying homogenous structure and not naively using all the  available data without an appropriate  challenge.